# Can't pull out the connection string from the configuration manager

Tags: c#, mysql, connection-string, configurationmanager

I know I just missing something simple, but when I try pulling the connection string from the ConfigurationManager, I always get null.

I have System.configuration added as a reference

In the source file I have

```
using System.Configuration;
using MySql.Data;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;
....
_connStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MySqlDataConnection"].ConnectionString;
objConnection = new MySqlConnection(_connStr);
```

where in my app config I have...

```
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="MySqlDataConnection"
       connectionString="server=127.0.0.1;database=HLSDB;uid=me;password=myPasswd;pooling=false;"
       providerName="MySql.Data.SqlClient"/>
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

Comment: I hate to say something that may seem lame but have you made sure that the correct config file is loaded? Because I do not see a single thing that is off in here. I looked at a system I am using similar and the only difference I have is I don't define the providerName in the node.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you could try

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.ConfigurationFile
```

To verify you are looking at the correct config file.

Answer (score 0):

Please double-check that your configuration file is deployed as `MyApplication.exe.config` (and not `app.config`) in the output directory.  That code you have posted is fine.